# How to hide vanilla buttons according to a field?

Tags: button, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

Is it possible to hide vanilla buttons (in my case crm save button), according to Javascript function or field change in Dynamics - Crm 2016 using workbench?  If it's optional where can I had the connection to my display rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a ribbon display rule.

[Control when ribbon elements are displayed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328560.aspx)

> By defining display rules in rule definitions, you can use the same
>   display rule for many command definitions. When more than one display
>   rule is defined for a command definition, all of the display rules
>   must evaluate as true for the ribbon element to be displayed.

This is easier using [Ribbon Workbench](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx). This [article](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/121427-enable-disable-a-ribbon-button-dynamically-based-o) is similiar but for enable rules. In later versions of CRM disabling a button usually hides it as well.

Comment: ok but can I use display rules on vanilla buttons? or should I create a new SAVE customize button ?

Comment: @Damkulul, you can usually create them on vanilla buttons

Comment: unforthunantly it didn't help in vanilla button case.. nothing happened can you be more specific about vanilla buttons?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the XrmToolbox: https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/
2. Open the Ribbon Workbench 2016
3. Open your ribbon
4. Right-click on the button you want to edit, click Customize command
5. Go in Solution Elements > Commands > Your command
6. Add a display rule
7. Add Step, Value Rule

If you to use javascript for a complex rule, instead add an Enable Rule and a step, CustomRule.